# PrimeFaces DataTable inside AccordionPanel null pointer after sort column

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, accordion

I have a `p:datatable` inside an `p:accordionPanel` with multiple tabs.
On the first load every thing goes ok.
If I sort the table inside the FIRST tab and update it through a `p:commandButton`, it works also.
If I sort the tables from the second (or third) tab, and try to update the component, it loads only the first tab and a null point exception is throwed.

```
Ago 02, 2016 5:23:58 PM com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback visit
GRAVE: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The page only back to work properly after a update the page.

**teste.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"  >
<h:head>

</h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form id="form">
<p:accordionPanel value="#{facesBean.negocios}" var="negocio" activeIndex="-1" id="ac-negocio" styleClass="accordion-negocios" style="overflow:hidden">
    <p:tab title="#{negocio.nome}">
        <p:dataTable  id="tabela-sistema"  var="sistema" value="#{negocio.sistemas}" widgetVar="wd-#{negocio.nome}">
            <p:column headerText="SISTEMA" sortBy="#{sistema.nome}">
                <h:outputText value="#{sistema.nome} "/>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </p:tab> 
</p:accordionPanel>

<p:commandButton value="Gerar" action="#{facesBean.gerarValores()}" update=":form" />
</h:form>
</h:body>

</html>
```

**FacesBean.java**

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class FacesBean {

    private List<Negocio> negocios = new ArrayList<Negocio>();

    public FacesBean(){
        System.out.println("Construct");
        gerarValores();
    }
    public void gerarValores() {
        negocios = new ArrayList<Negocio>();
        System.out.println("Gerar");
        Negocio negocio= new Negocio();
        negocio.setNome("negocio-1");
        List<Sistema> sistemas = new ArrayList<Sistema>();
        Sistema sistema = new Sistema();
        sistema.setNome("Sistema 1");
        sistemas.add(sistema);
        sistema = new Sistema();
        sistema.setNome("Sistema 2");
        sistemas.add(sistema);
        negocio.setSistemas(sistemas);
        negocios.add(negocio);

        Negocio negocio2= new Negocio();
        negocio2.setNome("negocio-2");
        sistemas = new ArrayList<Sistema>();
        sistema = new Sistema();
        sistema.setNome("Sistema 3");
        sistemas.add(sistema);

        sistema = new Sistema();
        sistema.setNome("Sistema 4");
        sistemas.add(sistema);
        negocio2.setSistemas(sistemas);
        negocios.add(negocio2);
    }

    public List<Negocio> getNegocios() {
        return negocios;
    }

    public void setNegocios(List<Negocio> negocios) {
        this.negocios = negocios;
    }       

}
```

PF Version 5.1 running on Apache Tomcat 7

After change the jsf from 2.1 to 2.2.4, the exception have changed

```
Ago 03, 2016 11:38:46 AM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
GRAVE: Error Rendering View[/teste.xhtml]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.findColumn(DataTable.java:785)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getSortColumn(DataTable.java:1268)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SortFeature.singleSort(SortFeature.java:135)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.preRender(DataTableRenderer.java:109)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:83)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1903)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
    at org.primefaces.component.accordionpanel.AccordionPanelRenderer.encodeTab(AccordionPanelRenderer.java:223)
    at org.primefaces.component.accordionpanel.AccordionPanelRenderer.encodeTabs(AccordionPanelRenderer.java:170)
    at org.primefaces.component.accordionpanel.AccordionPanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(AccordionPanelRenderer.java:103)
    at org.primefaces.component.accordionpanel.AccordionPanelRenderer.encodeEnd(AccordionPanelRenderer.java:76)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1903)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1896)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:559)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:381)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1740)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1740)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:399)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:319)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:60)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1004)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1896)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:425)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:72)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at br.com.gvt.autenticacao.FiltroLogin.doFilter(FiltroLogin.java:27)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Ago 03, 2016 11:38:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/DisponibilidadeSistemas] threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: CDATA tags may not nest
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlResponseWriter.startCDATA(HtmlResponseWriter.java:681)
    at javax.faces.context.ResponseWriterWrapper.startCDATA(ResponseWriterWrapper.java:179)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialResponseWriter.startError(PartialResponseWriter.java:341)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startError(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:174)
    at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:202)
    at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:126)
    at javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerWrapper.handle(ExceptionHandlerWrapper.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:72)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at br.com.gvt.autenticacao.FiltroLogin.doFilter(FiltroLogin.java:27)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Probably related to the scope of your bean. In this case it's better to use `@ViewScoped`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope

Comment: Or realated to the PrimeFaces or JSF version. Did you try the latest... Did you try if partialStateSaving makes a difference @JasperdeVries:  read the linked-in message last weekend  (kind of with a huge delay, still had an old email address in it, so missed the notifications). Will reply later this week.

Comment: @JasperdeVries change the scope to view or request did not work.

Comment: @Kukeljte after change the jsf version from 2.1 to 2.2.4 the error has became more complete. I've updated the post including the new stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I put

```
dynamic="true"
```

in the accordionPanel and everything worked fine.

```
  <p:accordionPanel id="sampleId" value="#{bean.sampleList}" var="rec" multiple="false" activeIndex="-1" dynamic="true">
```

Ι also have and

```
<p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{bean.onTabChange}" update="dataTable"
                            process="@form"/>
<p:ajax event="tabClose" listener="#{bean.onTabClose}"
                            update="sampleId:dataTable"/>
```